# Conditional removal of rows based on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 4 columns and 500+ rows.  I am looking to conditionally remove rows from the data frame based on multiple columns.

```
df.original
   chr   start    end   type     
1 chrI  232613  232625  ins  
2 chrI  834151  834151  snp  
3 chrI  834161  834161  snp  
4 chrI  834171  834177  del 
5 chrI 1123752 1123805  del 
6 chrI 1377649 1377649  snp
```

What I want to do is look at each row and see if the type (snp, ins, del) and chr match another row.  If that condition is true, I want to then look at the start and end positions.  If both the start and end positions are +- 50 from any other row I want to remove it and the other rows that are +-50.

```
df.new
   chr   start    end   type     
1 chrI  232613  232625  ins  
2 chrI  834171  834177  del 
3 chrI 1123752 1123805  del 
4 chrI 1377649 1377649  snp
```

In the new data frame the original rows 2 and 3 are both removed because they are on the same chr, same type, and both the start and end positions are +- 50 from each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're working with genes, represented as ranges of integers, it may be ideal to utilize the `GRanges` and `IRanges` package from bioconductor.

```
library(IRanges)
library(tidyverse) 

#Turn your data.frame into S4 object IRanges
IR <- IRanges(
  start = c(232613, 834151, 834161, 834171, 1123752, 1377649),
  end = c(232625, 834151, 834161, 834177, 1123805, 1377649),
  type = c("ins", "snp", "snp", "del", "del", "snp")
)
```

```
IR
>IRanges object with 6 ranges and 1 metadata column:
          start       end     width |        type
      <integer> <integer> <integer> | <character>
  [1]    232613    232625        13 |         ins
  [2]    834151    834151         1 |         snp
  [3]    834161    834161         1 |         snp
  [4]    834171    834177         7 |         del
  [5]   1123752   1123805        54 |         del
  [6]   1377649   1377649         1 |         snp
```

```
types <- mcols(IR)$type %>% unique()

#A loop (less than ideal) to make each 'type' a element of a list
list.IR <- list()
for(i in 1:length(types)){
  list.IR[i] <- IR[mcols(IR)$type == types[i]]
}
```

```
#create a function that removes IRanges with more than one overlap (ie, other than itself)
ovlp_rm <- function(IR){
  IR.flank <- flank(IR, width = 25, both = T)
  n_ovlp <- countOverlaps(IR.flank)
  indx_no.ovlp <- n_ovlp == 1
  return(IR[indx_no.ovlp])
}
```

```
#apply the function on your list of IRanges, organized by type
lapply(list.IR, FUN = ovlp_rm) 

>
> lapply(list.IR, ovlp_rm)
[[1]]
IRanges object with 1 range and 1 metadata column:
          start       end     width |        type
      <integer> <integer> <integer> | <character>
  [1]    232613    232625        13 |         ins

[[2]]
IRanges object with 1 range and 1 metadata column:
          start       end     width |        type
      <integer> <integer> <integer> | <character>
  [1]   1377649   1377649         1 |         snp

[[3]]
IRanges object with 2 ranges and 1 metadata column:
          start       end     width |        type
      <integer> <integer> <integer> | <character>
  [1]    834171    834177         7 |         del
  [2]   1123752   1123805        54 |         del
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be useful. You can group by `type` and then compute the number of elements as well as the differences between start/end variables. After that you can create a flag variable to identify the values to be removed and filter. Here the code using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df.original %>% 
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(N=n(),Diff=c(NA,diff(start)),
         Diff2=c(NA,diff(end))) %>%
  fill(c(Diff,Diff2),.direction = 'downup') %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Flag=ifelse(N>1 & abs(Diff)<50 & abs(Diff2)<50,1,0)) %>%
  filter(Flag==0) %>% dplyr::select(-c(N,Diff,Diff2,Flag))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  chr     start     end type 
  <chr>   <int>   <int> <chr>
1 chrI   232613  232625 ins  
2 chrI   834171  834177 del  
3 chrI  1123752 1123805 del  
4 chrI  1377649 1377649 snp
```